# Improvment of and looping in a regular expression pattern

Tags: python, regex

My implemented regex pattern contains two repeating symbols: `\d{2}\.` and `<p>(.*)</p>`. I want to get rid of this repetition and asked myself if there is a way to loop in Python's regular expression implementation.

**Note**: I do **not** ask for help to parse a XML file. There are many great tutorials, howtos and libraries. **I am looking for means to implement repetition in regex patterns.**

My code:

```
import re

pattern = '''
<menu>
<day>\w{2} (\d{2}\.\d{2})\.</day>
<description>
<p>(.*)</p>
<p>(.*)</p>
<p>(.*)</p>
</description>
'''

my_example_string = '''
<menu>
<day>Mi 03.04.</day>
<description>
<p>Knoblauchcremesuppe</p>
<p>Rindsbraten "Esterhazy" (Gem&uuml;serahmsauce)</p>
<p>mit H&ouml;rnchen und Salat</p>
</description>
</menu>
'''

re.findall(pattern, my_example_string, re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: Parsing XML with regex is usually wrong, what are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: The XML is malformed what prevents a usage of LXML and Xpath. I easily can retrieve the deserved data, but I want to find a way to avoid these repetitions in any regex patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, just for anyone who might read this: DO NOT take this as an excuse to parse your XML with regular expressions. It generally a really really bad idea! In this case the XML is malformed, so its the best we can do.

The regular expressions looping constructs are `*` and `{4}` which you already using. But this is python, so you can construct your regular expression using python:

```
expression = """
<menu>
<day>\w{2} (\d{2}\.\d{2})\.</day>
<description>
"""

for x in xrange(3):
    expression += "<p>(.*)</p>"

expression += """
</description>
</menu>
"""
```

Comment: What about `expression += "<p>(.*)</p>\n" * 3` ?